# pg-promise create function containing execute with $ parameter

Tags: node.js, postgresql, escaping, pg-promise, dollar-sign

I am trying to run database creation scripts through pg-promise.
The bit that execute the command in nodeJS is as follow :

```
        this.db.any(sql, [])
            .then((data: any) => {
                resolve(data);
            })
            .catch((error: any) => {
                console.log(sql);
                reject(error);
            });
```

The functions code might contain one or several $variables used directly inside the functions themselves (that is the reason why I am passing an empty array in the any above).  Parameters inside the execute statements are of several different types. an example is a follow :

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ze_function(i_a_parameter TEXT, i_a_value INTEGER, i_another_value TEXT) 
    RETURNS integer
    AS $function$
    DECLARE
        v_rows_saved integer := 0;
    BEGIN
        EXECUTE format('UPDATE %I_table
            SET
            the_field = $1
            the_other_field = $2', i_a_parameter)
            USING i_a_value, i_another_value;
        GET DIAGNOSTICS v_rows_saved = ROW_COUNT;
        RETURN v_rows_saved;
    END;
    $function$
    LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

and the error it generates is the following : 

    `RangeError: Variable $1 out of range. Parameters array length: 0`

I tried to find ways escape the dollar sign, with no luck so far.
Is it a complete no go, or are there ways of doing things I don't know yet ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise), in order to execute pre-formatted SQL like that, you need to make sure the query method does not try to format it.

That means passing in either `undefined` for values, or nothing at all:

```
this.db.any(sql)
```

Passing in `[]` results in method trying to format the SQL using `$1, $2, ...` format, and hence the error you are getting just as it finds those.

Comment: Yes, that works better... and nice spot on the error, I simplified the function, and forgot to put the according error message on it. Many thanks